# error: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am getting a value as a string from `cookie` which has multiple values stored in it.
I am separating these values with the use of the `split()` function, but I am  getting an error continuously. Here is my code. It would be a great help if anyone can help me out with this.

```
var sourcez = jQuery.cookie("Source");
var mediumz = jQuery.cookie("Medium");

function utmze(eutmz) {
  var utmz_val = jQuery.cookie("__utmzz");

  for (var o = utmz_val, r = o.split("|"), a = 0; (a < r.length); a++) {
    var t = r[a].split("=");

    if (t[0] == eutmz) {
      return t[1];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: Check to see if `utmz_val` is defined.

Comment: let us know what's the output of `console.log(utmz_val);`

Comment: The error says that you are trying to do something on an undefined object. In your case, it could be either `o` or `r[a]`. Besides that, your `for` definition is quite strange.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that string is not empty , null and undefined before you are performing the split action

```
function isValidString(input){
  if(input != null && input != '' && input != undefined){
     return true;
  }
  return false;
}
if(isValidString(input)){
   input.split('=');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the following changes to avoid the error:

```
var sourcez = jQuery.cookie("Source");
var mediumz = jQuery.cookie("Medium");

function utmze(eutmz) {
  var utmz_val = jQuery.cookie("__utmzz");

  for (var o = utmz_val, r = o.split("|"), a = 0; (a < r.length); a++) {
    if (typeof r[a] != "undefined") {  // Checking if the variable is defined.
      var t = r[a].split("=");

      if (t[0] == eutmz) {
        return t[1];
      }        
    }
  }
}
```